# Troubleshoot log in connection after changing server and adding wildcard ssl

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, database-connection, wildcard

I've moved hosting companies and a website I built (somehow) and manage has stopped working after trying to log in, it goes to a blank page and loads a 500 error.

I know from some digging the fault lies here: `$db = mysql_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die("Database connection failed");`

I have made sure I've changed the database connection details, I've tried changing the password.

I thought it might be linked with adding a wildcard ssl, but even removing it doesn't make any difference - although it still defaults to ssl.

Please can anyone help?

What have I missed please

As I said I've tried changing log in details,

When I try and log in with a correct user name & password, The url in the bar stays as the index page (where the screen is either blank or showing a 500 code), instead of progressing to the welcome page

Comment: What does your error log say?

Comment: Welcome, please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).